# Creating a simple control menu for a project and a loop prints a prompt more times than expected

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

My intention with this code is to use a switch statement to act as a simple control menu for a project I'm working on. The problem with this code is that the first "cout" statement prints out twice like this:

> > What would you like to do?
> >     (Press a letter):
> >
> > What would you like to do?
> >     (Press a letter):

Rather than what I had expected:

> > What would you like to do?
> >     (Press a letter):

Here is my code (I removed everything inside the case statements for readability):

```
char cMenu;

while (true) {
        cout << endl << "What would you like to do?" << endl <<"(Press a letter): " << endl;
        cin >> cMenu;

        switch (cMenu)
        {
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
        {
            cout << "*";
            break;
        }
        case 'J':
        case 'j':
        {
            cout << "*";
            break;
        }
        case 'S':
        case 's':
        {
            cout << "*";
            break;
        }
        case 'X':
        case 'x':
            cout << "*";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You likely have a character in the stream that is being read in by `cin >> cMenu` (new line perhaps?), but not processed by the corresponding switch statement, so the loop is actually running twice. Try ignoring everything in the `cin` stream (`cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()); cin.clear();`) prior to the loop executing.

Comment: Which compiler and OS are you using? Are you sure you don't have another `cout` somewhere inside the `switch` statement? As-is, I could not reproduce with VS2013 on Windows nor with g++ on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to u/lcs for reminding me that 'cin.ignore' exists.

My solution was to add the line:

```
 cin.ignore(100,'\n');
```

right before I get input for 'cMenu' to ignore any leading new lines.